# Find out if you are running in a command and the command parameters in Symfony

Tags: symfony

We have a service that can be called from a Symfony command and from a normal web request. Is there a way to find out if the service was called from a command or from a web request? If so, if it was called from a command, is there a way to find out the parameters that were used when running the command?

Comment: What about adding a variable for e.g. `$isCalledFromCommand` to the service which you set to `true` if it's called from the command? Same for the paramters. I think thats the simplest way

Comment: This seems a poor design. If you're calling from command use some kind of agnostic input or, if action to be performed are different, use some kind of decorator for basic functions and actual actions for web request and command.

Comment: We just need to do this for debugging an issue, it will be a temporary thing so I don't really want to alter the whole architecture of the platform

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this to know if the service is used from the cli, if it runs with apache you will get this `apache2handler`

```php
if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
  //some code
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 1):

In symfony Console,

> the command line context does not know about your VirtualHost or domain name

It means that you can check the request scheme, host, base_url and base path since these request properties have no values in the console context unless you configure them (https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally)